# Able to visit site from domain name but not IP address

Tags: .net, iis, dns, ip, ektron

We have our website running with IIS7, a very strange thing happened just recently.

I'm able to visit the site without issue with the domain name (www.***_***.com e.g. ), but if I actually enter the IP address (64.xx.xxx.xxx), it does not work and gave me a 404 resource not found error.

So I went to IIS on the prod server, it's even more strange that I could not even go to the site with the domain name either. So Neither the domain name nor IP address would work on the actual server, but on an external computer the domain name would work.

I then tried the "Browse Website Links" on IIS and it does seem to direct to the right file path however it keeps telling me the connect was reset and still failed to display the site.

Any thoughts on what could lead to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the IP on which your site is bound. If it is bound to "*" then change that to the actual IP of your site. If this is an enterprise environment then you might also want to check if address resolution is happening properly.

Comment: Thanks! after I bind the ip address on IIS, the IP does work now with no problem. However, if I try localhost it still lead me to the 404 page. So I went on to the host file under system32\drives\etc\ .. it says "localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself."

Any idea why is the localhost returning 404 while the site is actually running fine? Thanks!

Comment: localhost is not working because your website is now bound on a single specific IP. (the one that you just selected)

Comment: Could you mark the question answered if I was able to help :-)